# Menu bar is missing when accessing mobile chat from desktop

Tags: bug, design, chat, user-interface, accessibility

I use the mobile version of the Stack Exchange chat, even though I'm using a laptop, as it's easier on my sensory sensitivities as it has far fewer animations - I really can't follow the desktop version at all, for me it's like being unexpectedly smacked in the face every few seconds.

After comparing screenshots with a user who is using the mobile chat on a mobile phone, I've realised that the reason I can never find most of the features (search, edit, et cetera) is that they're supposed to be on a menu bar at the top and when I use the chat on my laptop this menu bar does not appear.

Here's a screenshot: https://paste.pics/b4e89e343013924e18c5a50546ff2caf

I don't know whether this is true for other people accessing the mobile chat from a desktop computer.  If so, it should really be fixed if possible, please, as an accessibility issue, since some people really will need to use the mobile version from a desktop and it's a pity if half the features are broken.

Comment: There is a new mobile chat UI available, in your chat profile settings, which has many more features. Does that work for you?

Comment: Ah!  Yes, I remember now.  That may account for it.  I can't use the new mobile chat UI because, again, too many animations.